# codeigniter data loading in bootstrap tabs

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I am new in codeigniter and developing a project using codeigniter and bootstrap.
I have a main controller named Welcome.php & the corresponding view for this controller is user_view.php. user_view.php basically contains three sections leftbar, header & body. I am able to pass data for each section except body. becasue it contains further sections and that depends on leftbar menu items click. I am successfull to load user_view.php by passing views for each sections initially. But when on click left bar menu items it calls a new controller named Invoice.php and corresponding view file is user_view which contains three tabs for body section. Now I am confused how to load data for tabs.
My flow are like this--

```
In User.php (Main Controller) 
function index(){
    $data = array(
                'nav' =>$this->load->view('nav_view','',true),
                'sidebar' =>$this->load->view('sidebar_view','',true),
                'content' =>$this->load->view('content_view','',true)
                );
            $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
}
```

In user_view.php (main controller view) body part

```
<?php echo $nav;?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- #sidebar-wrapper -->
        <?php echo $sidebar;?>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <?php echo $content;?>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

From side bar contains many links and onclicking one links i am calling another controller named Invoice.php and function taxable
    And Invoice.php is looks like this

```
public function taxable()
    {
        $data = array(
            'nav' =>$this->load->view('nav_view','',true),
            'sidebar' =>$this->load->view('sidebar_view','',true),
            'content' =>$this->load->view('invoice_taxable_view','',true),
            );
        $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
    }
```

invoice_taxable_view.php

```
<!-- Page Content -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">New Invoice</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Invoice Data</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Edit Invoice</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <p><?php $this->load->view('taxable_invoice_form',true); ?></p>
            </div>
          <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <p><?php $this->load->view('taxable_invoice_record',true); ?></p>
          </div>
          <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>EDIT INVOICE</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now here content section includes three tabs with forms. so how can i pass all three tabs content to main view. Or I have to make seperate view for it also.? and can i also directly load content for taxable_invoice_record.php. Because its data are coming from database. Should I choose for ajax call, but it spoil the MVC pattern. 
Please help me out. I am not getting any way and tried many possible ways.

Comment: you can use <?php echo $nav; echo $sidebar; echo $content;?> in view page after passing $data varaiable.

Comment: thanks safin. But how to pass $data variable

Comment: you mentioned it there...  $this->load->view('user_view',$data);

Comment: yes. But first time on loading its fine. But on left side bar link click it calls controller Invoice.php and from there I am loading data on main view that is user_view. And this time I am passing body content as invoice_taxable_view. This file contains 3 tabs. So wondering how to pass tab data while loading user_view from Invoice controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Initially I was trying to do is loading main view every time for each controller. And main view body part was every time changes. So it was getting difficult for me to pass body content every controller. I just drop the idea of keeping same maain view and load body content differently. Instead I created seprate views and add them header siderbar body as I was doing for Main controller. But Thanks to all and those who do hard work to main stackoverflow.

## HappyCoding